# Using PHP to show different chunks of HTML dependent on page id

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to use PHP to output different HTML for an image slider dependent on the body's page id of a wordpress site

I've tried the below, but being a newbie to PHP, i seem to be getting in a bit of a pickle instead. It just needs to be simple - I can do it via CSS however I'd rather not have all the images loading only to display a select few of them. I'd also rather not use a plugin if possible.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

```
<?php if($id == "page-id-19") {
?>
<div class="imageSlider"><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/Images/mainImages/innerPage-Image.jpg" alt="" /><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/Images/mainImages/innerPage-Image2.jpg" alt="" /><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/Images/mainImages/innerPage-Image3.jpg" alt="" /></div>
<?php
}
elseif ($id == "page-id-23") {
?>
<div class="imageSlider"><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/Images/mainImages/innerPage-Image4.jpg" alt="" /><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/Images/mainImages/innerPage-Image5.jpg" alt="" /><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/Images/mainImages/innerPage-Image6.jpg" alt="" /></div>
<?php
}
?>
```

**UPDATE******

I realised that the id was actually a class.

eg. "body class="page page-id-19 page-template page-template-inner-page-php"

However, when using the suggested solution below, it just doesn't doesn't output any HTML at all to the page... it's being called to the template page via an include -

```
    <?php
   switch($class){
     case "page-id-19":
?>
         <div class="imageSlider"><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/Images/mainImages/innerPage-Image.jpg" alt="" /><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/Images/mainImages/innerPage-Image2.jpg" alt="" /><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/Images/mainImages/innerPage-Image3.jpg" alt="" /></div>
<?php   
     break;
     case "page-id-23":
?>
         <div class="imageSlider"><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/Images/mainImages/innerPage-Image4.jpg" alt="" /><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/Images/mainImages/innerPage-Image5.jpg" alt="" /><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/Images/mainImages/innerPage-Image6.jpg" alt="" /></div>
<?php
     break;
   }
?>
```

Comment: Whereabouts are you trying to put the image slider? Insite the article, in a sidebar/footer? It makes a difference as to what information you have directly, and what you may need to go and get.

Comment: Hiya - I've created a PHP include file, which I'm calling into my page template(s).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$id`, try using `$post->ID`

Alternatively, you need to create the $id with:

```
$id = $post->ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood the question, but the way I understand what you're asking, I think you could best achieve this using a switch.

**The Switch:**

```
<?php
   switch($id){
     case "page-id-a":
?>
         Put your HTML here.
<?php   
     break;
     case "page-id-b":
?>
         Put your HTML here.
<?php
     break;
   }
?>
```

Where I put *page-id-a* or *page-id-b* , let these be what you currently have as *page-id-23* etc.

It's not as complex as it looks, and it's horrendously logical.

You can read up more on switches at :

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_switch.asp

Comment: Hiya - I realised that the id was actually a class, so i've changed your code to $class - but unfortunately nothing displays

Comment: The class is assigned to the body tag via <?php body_class(); ?> - is that what you mean? (there are multiple classes assigned the body - see update above)

Comment: Hi, probably a fault on my part. Do you actually have a way of getting the body class? I'm not 100% fluent with the Wordpress backend, but try replacing the "$class" in the switch with "body_class()". It might be completely wrong.

Also, you can look into adding a "default:" to the switch so something's always displayed.

Comment: Hiya - think you reedited your comment as i was replying to the original. I'll try your suggestion though - thanks for all your advice :)

Comment: Hi, Sorry, I hit delete by accident, too! My bad! Let me know how it goes. You're welcome!

Comment: Weirdly, that seems to be outputting the body class instead of the image slider HTML

Comment: Oh, I think that the body_class() function actually runs the echo inside itself. There's also the "get_body_class()" function as an alternative. Try that one instead?